# Accessing nested dictionary in json from python file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a intent.json file

```
{"intents": [
    {"tag": "greeting",
     "patterns": ["Hi there", "How are you", "Is anyone there?", "Hello", "Good day"],
     "responses": ["Hello, thanks for asking", "Good to see you again", "Hi there, how can I help?"],
     "context": [""]
    },
    {"tag": "goodbye",
     "patterns": ["Bye", "See you later", "Goodbye", "Nice chatting to you, bye", "Till next time"],
     "responses": ["See you!", "Have a nice day", "Bye! Come back again soon."],
     "context": [""]
    }
    ]
}
```

I have python file in which following function fetches the intent of the sentence and output is as follows

```
classify_local('Hello, good day!')
```

and output comes as

```
['greeting']
```

Now I want to fetch a response corresponding to tag greeting.
How can I do that?

Comment: check classify_local function it must be using "tag" key to return values, there you can change/add "responses" key as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parsing Through Nested JSON Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36144702/parsing-through-nested-json-python)

Comment: What output are you expecting ?

Comment: Is the third element in your `patterns` for the tag `greeting`, `"Hello", "Good day"` or `"Hello, good day!"`?

Comment: output I am expecting is "Hello, thanks for asking" or anything from the response @AbhishekKulkarni

Comment: No it is "Hello" , "Good day" only @akileshraj

Comment: so you want the first element from the response ?

Comment: yes @AbhishekKulkarni

Comment: You can have easily done that based on the code which i had sent

Comment: @kriti can you show 1 or 2 examples  more of how your `classify_local` should behave?  some input and some output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want the first response from all the responses for the tag `greeting` then it is,

```
json_value = {
    "intents": [
        {
            "tag": "greeting",
            "patterns": ["Hi there", "How are you", "Is anyone there?", "Hello", "Good day"],
            "responses": ["Hello, thanks for asking", "Good to see you again", "Hi there, how can I help?"],
            "context": [""]
        },
        {
            "tag": "goodbye",
            "patterns": ["Bye", "See you later", "Goodbye", "Nice chatting to you, bye", "Till next time"],
            "responses": ["See you!", "Have a nice day", "Bye! Come back again soon."],
            "context": [""]
        }
    ]
}


for intent in json_value['intents']:
    if intent['tag'] == 'greeting':
        response = intent['responses'][0]
print(response)
```

Comment: you give a response no matter the input of your function `classify_local`

Answer (score 2):

There's a ton of possible holes here, but given the expected output, this should work to figure out what type of intent the sentence has given the limited I/O provided.

```py
import string

def classify_local(text):
    # Separate out the phrases of the input text
    # "Hello, good day!" --> ['hello', 'good day']
    phrases = [
        s.translate(s.maketrans("", "", string.punctuation)).strip().lower()
        for s in text.split(",")
    ]

    # Find tags where all phrases are in patterns
    return [
        i["tag"]
        for i in intents_json["intents"]
        if all(j in [k.lower() for k in i["patterns"]] for j in phrases)
    ]


classify_local("Hello, good day!")
```

If you want a softer match, replace `all` in the return with `any`, but that's much less likely to be correct in a broader data set.

Keep in mind that this all falls apart very quickly when parsing written sentences against larger data sets.

Answer (score 2):

you could use regular expresions:

```
import re


my_json = {"intents": [
    {"tag": "greeting",
     "patterns": ["Hi there", "How are you", "Is anyone there?", "Hello", "Good day"],
     "responses": ["Hello, thanks for asking", "Good to see you again", "Hi there, how can I help?"],
     "context": [""]
    },
    {"tag": "goodbye",
     "patterns": ["Bye", "See you later", "Goodbye", "Nice chatting to you, bye", "Till next time"],
     "responses": ["See you!", "Have a nice day", "Bye! Come back again soon."],
     "context": [""]}]}


pattern_tag = {'|'.join(d["patterns"]): d['tag'] for d in my_json["intents"]}

def classify_local(my_strig):
    for p, t in pattern_tag.items():
        if re.search(p, my_strig):
            return t

classify_local('Hello, good day!')
```

output:

```
'greeting'
```

to read from your json file:

```
import json

with open('intent.json') as f:
    my_json = json.load(f)
```